# Rails Paperclip S3 rename thousands of files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, rename

I'm trying to rename a lot of files in s3--changing the current paperclip `has_attached_file` `:path` from `stuff/:id_:updated_at_:style.:extension` to `stuff/:id_:counter_:style.:extension`, where `:counter` is a field in the same model as the image.

I haven't the foggiest on how to rename all the files--preferably in a rake task.

Incidentally, I'll be incrementing `:counter` each time a new file is saved to the record.

This is Rails 3 and the latest Paperclip as of this posting.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm working on a solution using the aws-s3 gem to edit the S3 bucket directly.  I'll post an answer below once I've verified it works.... but I think it will.  : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
# This task changes all of the keys from the current format,
# :id_:image_updated_at_:style, to :id_:image_counter_:style.
# :image_counter is set arbitrarily at 1, since all records have
# a default of 1 in that field (until they're updated).
desc "One-time renaming of all the amazon s3 content for User.image"

task :rename_s3_files, [:bucket] => :environment do |t, args|
  require 'aws/s3'

  cred = YAML.load(File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml")).symbolize_keys!
  AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection! cred

  bucket = AWS::S3::Bucket.find(args[:bucket])

  # Rename everything in the bucket, taking out the timestamp and replacing it with "1"
  bucket.each do |obj|
    arr = obj.key.split('_')
    obj.rename(arr[0] + '_1_' + arr[2])
  end

end
```

It just goes through all the files in the bucket and renames them according to this new schema.  I set the :counter field in the Paperclip path to default to 1, thus the `_1_` in the new file name.

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Give paperclip's refresh rake task a try.  I've used it to generate new styles and I'm guessing it will pick up on your path change as well?

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation

Comment: I'm not sure this'll work--I need to rename the originals, not the thumbnails.  If I change the :path option to the format I want, it will of course not see the files anymore, so it won't be able to rename them with a reprocess.